# How do I properly used stored strings in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my program to open files with paths that I declare earlier in the program.

My declared string

```
char *pathToFile="/var/www/mcc-libhid/";
```

My current code

```
  fptr=fopen("configurationSettings.txt","r"))
```

How I want the program to read it:

```
ftpr=fopen("/var/www/mcc-libhid/configurationSettings.txt" , "r");
```

What is the syntax to do this?

Comment: For added safety it's best to declare `pathToFile` as `const char *pathToFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and prefix the path into the buffer.

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s/configurationSettings.txt", pathToFile);
```

and use `buf` in `fopen()`:

```
ftpr=fopen(buf, "r");
```

Comment: I corrected typos. Often you should check the return of `snprintf` (to be sure the result is complete). But in such cases, I don't do it.

Comment: Thank you! but I'm getting this error, error: expected ‘)’ before ‘sizeof’
 snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s/configurationSettings.txt", pathToFile);
. Any idea why?

Comment: @ShantCancik It should work. See: http://ideone.com/7l7Pmb Can you post the code that gives that error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf`

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH_LENGTH]
sprintf(buffer,"%s/configurationSettings.txt",pathToFile);
```

The buffer variable will have the string `/var/www/mcc-libhid/configurationSettings.txt`

Comment: Avoid `sprintf` (avoid buffer overflows). Use `snprintf`

Comment: As long as you give sufficient length for the buffer. It should work fine.

Comment: But you usually don't know the maximal length (or it is too big to sit in a local variable). So really, don't recommend `sprintf`; the cost of the extra size argument in `snprintf` is negligible, and it is *so safer* ! `sprintf` (and `strcat` BTW) are almost as unsafe as `gets` are so should never be recommended for a newbie.